# Accessible introduction to category theory from the point of view of preorders.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, category-theory

Are there books renowned for introducing category theory in a very accessible way? An emphasis on the point of view that **categories generalize preorders** would be especially appreciated.

My goal is to be able to read [Categories, Allegories](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0444703683) in the end.

Comment: It doesn't get easier than "Conceptual Mathematics" by Lawvvere and Schanuel.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/ etc.

Comment: How about _Locally presentable and accessible categories_? It even has the word ‘accessible’ in the title! (I jest!)

Comment: Joy of Cats? Free to boot!