# Non-disjointness of hom-sets

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

In the category $\bf Set$ of sets, $\mathcal C$ is the class of all sets. Given
sets $A$, $B$ the set $\text{Hom}(A, B)$ consists of all functions from $A$ to
$B$.

This is a standard example of a category but I did not understand how they ensure that $\text{Hom}$ is disjoint, that is

For any $(A,B)\neq(C,D)$ then $\text{Hom}(A,B)\cap\text{Hom}(C,D)=\emptyset,$

where $A,B.C,D\in\mathcal C.$ Let $1_A$ be an identity map so $1_A\in\text{Hom}(A,A)$. Since $A\subset B$, we have the inclusion map $i\colon A\to B$ with $i\in\text{Hom}(A,B).$ Thus $1_A$ and $i$ are mathematically the same, so $$\text{Hom}(A,A)\cap \text{Hom}(A,B)\neq \emptyset.$$ I know I am wrong since $\mathcal C$ is definitely a category. Can anyone help me understand what I did wrong?

Also, what is a good reference as a starting point to get a better understanding of the notation of category theory?

Comment: Disjointness of homs is irrelevant, and only used by some authors as a mental crutch. Let me give you a non-category-theoretic similar problem: a function in ZFC is a set of ordered pairs. A function does not 'know' about its codomain, and functions with different codomains can be given by the same sets. Is this a problem with using ZFC? No.

Comment: @theHigherGeometer, I know that function is just a set in set theroy. But I did not get your point. Could you please explain? Thank you

Comment: Sorry for slow reply. What I meant is that your worry is not specific to category theory, it shows up already in ZFC. Otherwise Martin's answer is probably more helpful than my random comments (I'm the David, btw, that he refers to)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the bigger picture.

It is important in category theory that every morphism $f$ has a well-defined domain $\mathrm{dom}(f)$ as well as a well-defined codomain $\mathrm{cod}(f)$. When you define a category as a tuple consisting of two (large) sets $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$, $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ and functions $\mathrm{dom},\mathrm{cod} : \mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ as well as identity and composition (these are not important here, all what I say applies equally to directed multigraphs) this holds by definition.

However, another way of defining categories is by giving $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ and a function which associates to every pair of objects $A,B \in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ a set $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$. In order to get a category as defined above, we define $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ as the *disjoint* union of these sets, i.e. as
$$\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C}) := \bigcup_{(A,B) \in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})^2} \mathrm{Hom}(A,B) \times \{(A,B)\}.$$
Conversely, given $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$, we define $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B) := \{f \in \mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C}) : \mathrm{dom}(f)=A,\, \mathrm{cod}(f)=B\}$.

These constructions are inverse to each other, but only in a certain sense: $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ is only isomorphic to the disjoint union of its Hom-sets, and conversely each Hom-set is isomorphic to the set of morphisms with given domain and codomain. It is not true that they are equal, but of course this does not matter at all in mathematical practice. When we start with $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$, the Hom-sets will be disjoint, but this is not true for other other approach.

Generally speaking, if we have a family of sets $(X_i)_{i \in I}$, their disjoint union $X := \coprod_{i \in I} X_i$ does not have the $X_i$ as subsets in the traditional sense of [ZFC](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ZFC), but there are only injections $X_i \to X$. The images of the $X_i$ are disjoint, but the $X_i$ themselves are not in general.

But we have to ask ourselves the following question: does it actually make sense to ask if two abstract sets $X,Y$ are disjoint or not? Of course this is a very meaningful question if $X,Y$ are both subsets of a given set, but when there is no relation between $X$ and $Y$, what does it even mean that an element of $X$ is *equal* to an element of $Y$? All this works fine with ZFC where everything is a set and we have intersections and unions of all pairs of sets, but it enables us also to ask nonsense questions such as "Is the set of transcendental numbers disjoint to the set of smooth plane curves?". As you, see this is a "type error". This is fixed by structural set theories such as [ETCS](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS) and even more by type theoretic foundations such as [HoTT](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+type+theory).

In structural set theories, there is no way of even *saying* that two random sets are disjoint or not. (We can say that two *morphisms* $A \to X$, $B \to X$ are disjoint, namely $A \times_X B = 0$.) In other words, the whole problem asked here just does not exist. And that being said, it also does not exist in mathematical practice. The reason is that almost all meaningful statements in category theory not involve "loose" morphisms without any known domain or codomain, but rather morphisms with a given domain and codomain. Secondly, we should never compare two morphisms $f : A \to B$ and $g : A' \to B'$ unless it is known that $A = A'$ and $B = B'$. If we want to do that, we should use commutative squares instead.

I hope all this explains a bit more David's comment above, saying "Disjointness of homs is irrelevant".

Answer (score 6):

You raise a good point. It is is actually standard to define the morphisms of $\mathbf{Set}$ to be ordered triples $(f,A,B)$ where $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$, which solves this issue.

Comment: subrosar, this will do but it did not say anything in book like that

Comment: @00GB Some authors implicitly assume that a function is an ordered triple $(f,A,B)$. Of course this is not the standard set-theoretic definition.

Comment: subrosar, Do you know anyone? Also, do you recommend any book, not more advance for category theory.

Comment: I've only read Categories for the Working Mathematician by Mac Lane which is admittedly pretty dense and abstract. Wikipedia is always a good resource. Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/good-books-and-lecture-notes-about-category-theory for more.

Comment: I agree with what subrosar said.

Just a minor remark, which may explain the notational confusion: Bourbaki [in 1954](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_function_concept#Notion_of_%22function%22_in_contemporary_set_theory) defined functions as triples.

Also, there is a footnote in [Rotman's Homological Algebra](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387245270) saying that whenever $\mathrm{Hom}(A, B)$ are not disjoint, they should be simply replaced by $\mathrm{Hom}(A, B) \times \{A\} \times \{B\}$.