# Are the following definitions of a finitely generated $k$-algebra equivalent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, finitely-generated

In my lecture notes for algebraic geometry, an algebra over a field $k$ is defined as a (unital and commutative) ring, together with a ring homomorphism $\lambda:k\to R$ (such a homomorphism preserves $1$). Using $\lambda$, we can define a scalar multiplication $k\times R\to R$ by $c\cdot f=\lambda(c)f$.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_algebra), a *finitely generated $k$-algebra* $R$ is defined as an algebra over $k$ for which there exist $a_1,\dots,a_n \in R$ such that the evaluation homomorphism $\phi_a:k[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to R$ is surjective. However, in my lecture notes, it defines a finitely generated $k$-algebra as an algebra over $k$ for which there exists a surjective homomorphism $\psi:k[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to R$ (there is no requirement that such a homomorphism is an evaluation homomorphism). Are these two definitions equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. By the universal property of the polynomial algebra, any $k$-algebra homomorphism $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n] \to R$ is the evaluation homomorphism for some elements $a_1,\dotsc,a_n \in R$, namely the images of the variables.

Albeit, the conceptually correct definition is even different. If $R$ is any sort of algebraic structure (group, abelian group, monoid, algebra, ring, Lie algebra, lattice, ...), it is called finitely generated if there are finitely many elements that generate $R$, and this means that $R$ is the smallest subalgebra containing these elements. You don't need free algebraic structures to formulate (and prove) that. For example, you want to know what finitely generated groups are without necessarily using free groups. Also, in the case of finitely generated field extensions: there is no free field extension.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I was wondering why "finitely generated" seemed to have a very different definition for algebras compared to rings or groups. I share your frustration when authors give a characterisation of a concept as the definition. Do you have any advice for where I can learn more about universal properties? I only know the absolute basics of category theory (the definition of a category, isomorphisms, retractions, sections, and a little bit about products and coproducts).

Comment: To get started I can highly recommend Tom Leinster's [Basic Category Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09375). After that, there are multiple options (just take one). Mac Lane, Borceux, Riehl, and many others (and if you know German, [that](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-53521-9) might be a choice ). You will also find answered literature questions on this site with recommendations - such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370).